# Broken YouTube Watch Later Button

Tags: youtube

Recently, my YouTube "Watch Later" button just stopped working. I've tried clearing my cache and history - To no success. 
I the "..." kebab icon still works, but I'm not looking for a workaround.

How Do I fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting like questions are off-topic in Web Applications SE.

Answer (score 1):

There could be browser extensions interfering with the way the Youtube website works. Try disabling all extensions in your web browser. You can do in Chrome with the command line option `--disable-extensions`.

Or go to the web address `chrome://extensions` and disable the extensions that has access to the YouTube website.

Answer (score -1):

YouTube fixed itself yesterday.

I had submitted a report earlier on, 
They may have just got arou